# QGIS Actions in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, actions

I am creating an action in QGIS, which opens a link from an attribute.

Is it possible to open such a link in QField (Android App)? Or is there any other way to open links from the attribute table in QField?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For now, QField does not recognize clickable URL. An issue has been reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/709), let's wait for this enhancement.